# link to non-category page routed to category template

Tags: templates

Working on a theme I was surprised when a link to an about page (about is not a category) is routed to the category template. Why is this so?

The template file for the about page is default. Then I changed the template of the about page to 'page' - and now it routes to single.php.

The question is how does an about page with a default template get routed to category.php?

Comment: We can not know how you have coded the theme to make that, it is not happeing by default. We don't what the [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) that your theme is using neither. So, it is very unlikely you will get an answer. Please, provide more information.